# Items being reordered in LongListSelector

Tags: windows-phone-8, mvvm, longlistselector, ui-virtualization

In my WP8 app, I'm using LongListSelector to display data items. Grouping works, jump list works.

I have the usual master/detail scenario here - click on item in the list, new page shows up with more information.

The problem is with navigating back to the page with LongListSelector. The list is basically messed up - *items are randomly reordered*, even between groups. Clicking on an item works properly - `ShowItemInfo` receives view model for the item the user clicked on.

Previously I was using ListBox, which too suffered from this issue. But I could disable virtualization by using default StackPanel as items panel. I don't know how to disable virtualization on LongListSelector (I don't want to, but the bug is horrible).

View model is simple. I'm using Caliburn.Micro, its conventions and `BindableCollection` for list of groups. I populate the list just once with `AddRange` method.

When the page is navigated back to, I'm not doing anything - and I even can't since I use MVVM and Caliburn.Micro. The items are loaded into list in `OnInitialize` callback, which *is invoked* only once during lifetime of view model.

The XAML for view is this:

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
    <Grid.Resources>
        <phone:JumpListItemBackgroundConverter x:Key="BackgroundConverter"/>
        <phone:JumpListItemForegroundConverter x:Key="ForegroundConverter"/>

        <Style x:Key="ListJumpListStyle" TargetType="phone:LongListSelector">
            <Setter Property="ItemTemplate">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Border Background="{Binding Converter={StaticResource BackgroundConverter}}"
                                HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding GroupTitle}" 
                                       Foreground="{Binding Converter={StaticResource ForegroundConverter}}" />
                        </Border>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </Grid.Resources>

    <phone:LongListSelector x:Name="Items" LayoutMode="List" IsGroupingEnabled="True"
                            JumpListStyle="{StaticResource ListJumpListStyle}">

        <phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid cal:Bind.Model="{Binding}"
                      cal:Message.Attach="[Event Tap] = [ShowItemInfo($dataContext)]"
                      Background="Transparent">
                    <TextBlock x:Name="ItemText" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextTitle2Style}" />
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>

        <phone:LongListSelector.GroupHeaderTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Border>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding GroupTitle}" />
                </Border>
            </DataTemplate>
        </phone:LongListSelector.GroupHeaderTemplate>

    </phone:LongListSelector>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've narrowed down the issue to the data template, more specifically the attached property `Bind.Model`, which allows Caliburn.Micro to bind view model to view:

```
<DataTemplate>
    <Grid cal:Bind.Model="{Binding}"
          cal:Message.Attach="[Event Tap] = [ShowItemInfo($dataContext)]"
          Background="Transparent">
        <TextBlock x:Name="ItemText" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextTitle2Style}" />
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

When this view is changed to use explicit bindings instead conventions (and `Bind.Model` attached property is removed), `LongListSelector` works like a charm.

<strike>I believe there has to be a bug within Caliburn.Micro, which causes this issue. Initially, I thought the bug was in the 1.5.2 version, which I'm using (unfortunately I have to), and that it was fixed in new 2.x versions. However, that is not true, the bug is still manifesting in latest stable version 2.0.2.</strike>

I was using this technique in WPF without any problems. I've also tried running the app in emulators for WP8.0 and WP8.1, but the behavior is the same.

<strike>If anybody finds out, what causes this bug (or new version of Caliburn.Micro fixes it), feel free to edit answer or post a comment. I would be happy to use conventions in data templates again.</strike>

**My mistake**: for data templates, `Bind.ModelWithoutContext` should be used. Even documentation [explicitly says](https://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=All%20About%20Actions) so:

> **Bind.ModelWithoutContext** - View-First - Set’s the Action.Target to the specified instance. Applies conventions to the view. (Use inside
>   of DataTemplate.)

With `Bind.ModelWithoutContext` LongListSelector works properly as it should (with conventions in item template).